# How would I make a whiteboard for an odd sized space?

Tags: walls

I want to make a white board (or something that will work for dry erase markers) to go in a place that you can not really buy for.

The space is only 10.5 inches high and 180 inches long. I was looking for a way that is not too expensive but still works well,

One idea was to get a long piece of laminated paper to hang up.

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: buy a 3ft by 5ft white board. remove the trim. cut off three lengths, each 10.5 x 60. re-trim it with wood or aluminum.

Comment: http://diy.stackexchange.com/search?q=whiteboard

Answer (score 1):

Dry erase paint is available from a few different manufacturers.

- [IdeaPaint](http://www.ideapaint.com/)
- [Rust-Oleum Dry Erase Paint](http://www.rustoleum.com/product-catalog/consumer-brands/specialty/dry-erase/)

Are a couple examples.

When I was in college, I bought a sheet material from Home Depot that had a smooth white finish.  I don't remember what it was, but it worked well as a makeshift Whiteboard.  If I remember correctly, it was a thin sheet of MDF coated on one side with acrylic. They sold it in 4x8' sheets, which could be easily cut to fit. The only down side was that if marks were left on it for a long time, they had to be cleaned off using dry erase cleaner spray.

It may have been [Thrifty White](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Thrifty-White-32-sq-ft-Hardboard-Panel-Board-709106/202090193#.UnPd7Pk3u2V).

Comment: I have looked at this and it is a little expensive, over $200

Comment: @shane Sorry, you didn't specify what "expensive" meant.

Answer (score 0):

You can purchase *[marker board](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Unbranded-3-16-in-x-2-ft-x-4-ft-Marker-Board-4-Pack-7012090/203444176#.UnPiVPmKK8A)* at big box stores.

The illustrated item is 2x4 ft, but it may be available in panels up to 8 ft. You can mount it in a frame and hang it or mount it permanently to the wall using glue.

Answer (score 0):

The cheap option is "shower panels" or also called "tileboard". It's typically a 4x8 sheet of hardboard with a white, shiny, laminate coating. Usually less than $20. Typically used as wall panels in a low-cost laundry room or basement bathroom or the like.

Cut it to size, stick it to the wall with some liquid nails.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy dry erase wallpaper.  It works well in my experience and comes in long rolls.  We had a conference room that had this on every wall from floor to ceiling and it was very nice.

I don't have experience with any specific brand but a [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=dry+erase+wallpaper) turned up [this](http://mywhiteboards.com/polritdryerw.html).